# How can refresh editor after action event in backoffice - HYBRIS?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

how can refresh editor after action event in backoffice.

For example If i go in /backoffice -> order and for some order click on cancel I want after cancel event to refresh ticket editor not only save event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Backoffice framework provides an ability to listen both for application and backoffice related events.

```
public class MyWidgetController extends DefaultWidgetController
{

    @GlobalCockpitEvent(eventName = "de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.event.events.AfterSessionUserChangeEvent", scope = CockpitEvent.APPLICATION)
    public void handleUserChange(final CockpitEvent event)
    {
        Messagebox.show("Session user changed");
    }
}
```

Take a look at the documentation for details - https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c39570386691014a7d98113f9920a82.html